# Select String value as Integer in Grafana with Influxdb

Tags: grafana, influxdb, home-automation

I would like to show a string value as a boolean or int value in a timeseries graph (data coming from home-assistant)

What I have:

```
> select temperature, hvac_action_str from state where entity_id = 'my_entity_id'
name: state
time                temperature hvac_action_str
----                ----------- ---------------
1574189734402651904 20          idle
1574189824323437056 19          idle
1574190158807940864 19          heating
1574190462736049920 19          heating
1574190766798977024 19          idle
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
> select temperature, (hvac_action_str == 'heating' ? 1 : 0) as isHeating from state where entity_id = 'my_entity_id'
name: state
time                temperature isHeating
----                ----------- ---------------
1574189734402651904 20          0
1574189824323437056 19          0
1574190158807940864 19          1
1574190462736049920 19          1
1574190766798977024 19          0
```

Is this possible?

The main goal is to create a graph like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pgHZ.png)

### Edit

I did not manage to get this to work with InfluxDb. I changed the main database of homeassistant to PostgreSQL.
With PostgreSQL as datasource in Grafana I did manage to get the desired graph using following query:

```
> SELECT
  created AS "time", 
  CAST(attributes::json->>'current_temperature' AS float) AS "current_temperature",
  CAST(attributes::json->>'temperature' AS float) AS "temperature",
  CASE WHEN attributes::json->>'hvac_action' = 'heating' THEN CAST(attributes::json->>'current_temperature' AS float) ELSE 0 END AS "isHeating",
  state AS "state"
FROM states 
WHERE
  entity_id = 'my_thermostat' AND
  $__timeFilter(created)
ORDER BY created;
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Clearly we are both trying to recreate the home-assistant climate graphs in Grafana.

Comment: @JohanHenkens, I updated main post

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible (at least with InfluxQL). You may use Flux (next generation of query language for InfluxDB), where you can try [strings.countStr() function](https://v2.docs.influxdata.com/v2.0/reference/flux/stdlib/strings/countstr/), e.g.:

```
import "strings"

data
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({
      r with
      _value: strings.countStr(v: r.hvac_action_str, substr: "heating")
    })
  )
```

Comment: I don't seem to get the Flux datasource plugin to work in Grafana just yet

Comment: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-influxdb-flux-datasource

Answer (score 0):

I created a similar grafana query to read and display climate thermostat for Home Assistant with MySQL backend, if anyone is interested:

```sql
SELECT
  created AS "time",
  CASE WHEN JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attributes, '$.hvac_action')) = 'heating' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "isHeating",
  CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attributes, '$.current_temperature')) AS DECIMAL(3,1)) AS "current_temperature",
  CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attributes, '$.temperature')) AS DECIMAL(3,1)) AS "target_temperature"
FROM states
WHERE
  entity_id = "climate.main_thermostat" AND
  state <> "unavailable" AND
  $__timeFilter(created)
ORDER BY created
```

Home Assistant `configuration.yaml` to log to MySQL:

```yaml
recorder:
  #purge_keep_days: 5
  db_url: mysql://dbusername:dbpassword@core-mariadb:3306/dbname?charset=utf8
  exclude:
    domains:
      - automation
      - updater
    entity_globs:
      - sensor.weather_*
    entities:
      - sun.sun # Don't record sun data
      - sensor.last_boot # Comes from 'systemmonitor' sensor platform
      - sensor.date
    event_types:
      - call_service # Don't record service calls
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work in Grafana/Influxdb by counting the amount of results with a given string value:
`SELECT count(result) AS "result" FROM /.*-.*/ WHERE $timeFilter AND result = 'FAIL' GROUP BY time(10s) fill(null)`

So, for your purposes it would be something like:
`select count(hvac_action_str) from state where entity_id = 'my_entity_id' and hvac_action_str != 'idle' GROUP BY time(10s) fill(null)`